# Where can I ask my question concerning home insurance?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

**Question I would like to ask**

Recently, I accidentally dropped a glass of wine on the carpet of the apartment I am renting. I have an insurance ([square one](https://www.squareoneinsurance.ca/)) but they refuse to cover the cost. When I signed the contract (1.5 years ago) I asked a few questions to know what would be covered by the insurance. It just so happens I asked them whether a red wine stain would be covered, and they answered "Yes".

Am I covered for my red wine stain?

If yes, what can I do to force them to respect our agreement?

**Where can I ask my question?**

I was thinking about [homeImprovement.SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) but it does not appear to be the right place. I thought about [expatriates.SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as I am living as an expatriate in Canada but I don't think it would be on-topic either.

Can you help me to find a SE (or non SE) site on which my question would be on-topic?

Comment: Legal issue. Possibly [law.se], but be sure to read their help center documentation (in particular what is and is not on topic there). I do not participate there and this could very well be off topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely a legal question, however at first glance it appeared something fit for the Money SE.

So, the [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) would be the best place for this. However, please do read their [Help-Center knowledgebase](https://law.stackexchange.com/help) properly before framing and posting your answer, so that your question would not be considered off-topic.