# Where can I ask a question about health insurance?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Recently my wife used quite a few services of a healthcare provider. She is covered with my health insurance as a dependent; as well as with her own health insurance. In the hospital my wife was always mentioning both insurances, but used mine as the primary one.

After about a month, I receive a document from my insurance company titled "Other coverage inquiry". Basically, they'd like to know whether my wife is covered with any other insurance (which is the case).

The document starts with the phrase I don't trust at all:

> By coordinating benefits for you or other family members who have additional health coverage, we may be able to reduce your out-of-pocket expenses for covered services.

I would like to know what are the possible **legal *and* financial implications** of disclosing or not disclosing my wife's second insurance. What would be the right SE site to ask this question on?

Comment: As your question is tailored to your specific case I doubt it is on-topic anywhere as we want questions to be general applicable and useful for future visitors. You better contact a lawyer and/or a financial consultant instead of asking random people on the internet.

Comment: @rene a) I can rephrase the question so that it's not specific to my case only; b) how come the other question is not off-topic on SE then (namely, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278342/where-can-i-ask-my-question-concerning-home-insurance) ?

Comment: I'm only repeating what is said in the help of Law.SE: [*Please don't ask questions seeking legal advice on a specific matter.*](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I don't see that explicit  restriction on Money.se: https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic so your question might fit there but I'm not a regular on any of these sites so better ask on their meta or chat before posting.

Comment: @rene this is a matter of rephrasing IMO. But I'll ask on both law & money meta sites, I think... As far as the "ask the layer and/or financial consultant" suggestion goes, I'm skeptical. Those people don't bear any responsibilities of their good or bad advice. I don't see how they are better or worse than any stranger(s) in the internet... Thanks for the references though!

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you get the problems with the insurance sorted out in a for you acceptable manner. Take care.

Comment: If you are looking for professional legal advice, it is best to seek independent advice from a trained professional. On Stack Exchange anyone can answer and the advice may not be as accurate than if you consulted a solicitor, although posting here is much cheaper

Comment: @jakesymons "professional" advisors bear no responsibility for their advice AND are too expensive. What's the point? Also, SE is a source of knowledgeable people who can provide as good suggestions as the professionals you're referring to.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko It is the basic terms and conditions that any information listed by the users of the site. It is clause 5 of the legal document. I am making sure that you were aware of this to avoid causing further distress to you and your wife.

Comment: @jakesymons I know that things posted on the Internet are just opinions. So are the legal advice made by professionals. I'm seeking the information, not a way to make someone on SE responsible for the opinion expressed. :)

Comment: I think it would be on topic on Personal Finances and Money.  I suggest you rephrase the last sentence to ask: "What would be the ramifications of just ignoring this request from my insurance company?"  Don't specifically ask for legal or medical advice on SE.